# Powershell giving weird result when i try to create ArrayList using Function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-5.1

```
$myList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$x = 109
$y = 176

$xList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$xList = @("A1" )
$myList.Add(@{"Key1" = $x; "Key2" = $xList})

$yList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$yList = @("B1")  
$myList.Add(@{"Key1" = $y; "Key2" = $yList})

$var = ($myList | ConvertTo-Json)
Write-Host $var
```

Above is the code without Function and below is the same code with Function of Powershell Function

```
Function XYZ
{
 param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][string[]] $CountName,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)][int32[]] $Count
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)][int16] $Repeat)
  $myList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  for ($i=0 ; $i -lt $Repeat ; ++$i){
      $list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
      $countVar = $CountName[$i]
      $list = @($countVar)
      $myList.Add(@{"Key1" = $Count[$i]; "Key2" = $list})
  }
  #$var = ($myList | ConvertTo-Json)   
  #Write-Host $var                        #Print 1
  return $myList
}
$x = 109
$y = 176
$z = $x, $y 
$values = @('A1', 'B1')
$result =  XYZ -CountName $values -Count $z -Repeat 2

$var = ($result | ConvertTo-Json)
Write-Host $var
```

Results are NOT SAME:

```
[
 0,
 1,
 {
     "Key1":  109,
     "Key2":  ["A1"]
 },
 {
    "Key1":  176,
    "Key2":  ["B1"]
 }
]
```

I do NOT get 0,1 in my json when i execute code withOUT Function..
Where is my code WRONG?
Print 1 gives right result though

Comment: In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command, an operator-based expression, or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent to a file or via the pipeline to another command) is _implicitly output_ from a script or function. To simply _discard_ such output, use `$null = ...`.
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects). 
See the linked duplicate for more information.

Comment: i agree and ok to close this question